# How to scale the x axis of a chart to only show the last 60 seconds of data

Tags: c#, graph, charts, scale

I have a chart on a windows form using c#. I am outputting data to the chart dynamically using:

```
Chart1.Series["Roll"].Points.AddXY(TimeStamp, roll);
Chart1.Series["Pitch"].Points.AddXY(TimeStamp, pitch);
```

I am wondering how to set the scale of the X axis to be a set interval size. I want the Chart to only show data for say the last 60 seconds.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/7094400/895114

Comment: ^ i have similar problem

Answer (score 2):

Once you reach 60 points, you can remove points and have it recalculate the axis min/max, as in [Chart control X axis growing and growing and it looks like it not moving](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21894191/chart-control-x-axis-growing-and-growing-and-it-looks-like-it-not-moving) . Alternatively, you can just tell it the new min/max, something like:

```
Axis xaxis = Chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX;
xaxis.Minimum = xaxis.Maximum - 60;
```

Might also need a call to `Chart1.ResetAutoValues();` and/or `xaxis.IntervalType = Seconds;` before changing the minimum to get things to work.