# Chart control X axis growing and growing and it looks like it not moving

Tags: c#, charts

I have application with real time Chart control that received date and display this on my control:

This is my control:

```
MyObject obj...

Series series = new Series();
series.Color = Color.Blue;
series.ChartType = SeriesChartType.Spline;
series.BorderWidth = 2;
chart1.Series.Add(series);
chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.MajorGrid.LineColor = Color.White;
chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.MajorGrid.LineColor = Color.White;
chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.IsStartedFromZero = true;
chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.IntervalOffsetType = DateTimeIntervalType.Number
;
```

Timer tick:

```
private void chartTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        series.Points.Add(wf.BitsPerSecond * 0.000001);
        chart1.ResetAutoValues();
}
```

my problem is that at the beginning this is the graph:

[image]

After few minutes the X axis is growing and growing and it looks like the graph stop to moving:

[image]

how can i make sure my graph will be look at the beginning ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You keep adding points to the chart, but don't ever remove them. So, when you call `chart.ResetAutoValues()`, it sets the minimum on the x-axis below the x value of your first point, and the maximum above (or equal to) the x value of your last point. The maximum keeps getting bigger, but the minimum never changes, so the graph looks compressed as time goes on. You can start to remove points once you reach some threshold, like this:

```
private void chartTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (series.Points.Count() > 1000) series.Points.RemoveAt(0);
    series.Points.Add(wf.BitsPerSecond * 0.000001);
    chart1.ResetAutoValues();
}
```

Comment: But also in this way i can see that X axis is still growing and growing

Comment: The min and max will still grow, because you keep adding points. The difference between the min and max should not grow once you reach a steady state (you'll always be looking at 1000 points' worth of data)

Comment: So what should i changed in order this graph to remained like at the beginning state ?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "like the beginning state" now.

Comment: i mean like the first picture i added

Comment: What about the first picture is correct? Do you want the graph to always look exactly like that? Do you want the resolution to always be like that (i.e., always show the same number of points)? Is there something else wrong with the second picture that's right in the first picture?

Comment: Yes, that what i want, the resolution to always be like that (i.e., always show the same number of points)

Comment: Then the code example I provided above will do that. You just need to adjust the threshold from 1000 to whatever looks good.