# How to draw graph using chart in .net windows forms based on time(seconds)

Tags: c#, vb.net, time, graph, charts

My requirement is to draw a graph using chart control in .net(windows form or WPF) in c# or vb.net which will update data from a serial port.The graph should show the received data and plot the load value(y axis) against time(x axis).The interval should be in seconds and it should keep on moving to the left like in ECG or Oscilloscope.

I made the graph but it is not scaling for second intervals and not moving and redrawing to the left.

Comment: For moving with the new data see my anwer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23542701/chart-compression/27077902#27077902)! - For the right scaling, please show us the code you have so far!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a built in chart function.
I guess you need to split this up.

＞Make an array, to hold some data points.

＞Then use a timer, and the OnTimerEvent method, to put the next data point in the array, and move along, deleting the last one.

＞and then refresh--delete and add--all the chart data points from the array values

Timer:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/393k7sb1(v=vs.110).aspx

Sorry I can't think of a simple way

Comment: The OP mentions the built-in Chart Control and also states that it gets data.. He is just not happy with two thing in the display!