# winform chart - function which behaves like user selection

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, charts

Need:

I want to implement a control (E.g. checkbox) that when the user invokes it,
it simulates the behaviors of user selection and zooms around a specific point range in the chart, in other words, narrows the X and Y range of the chart.

I did not find any reference on how to achieve the auto zooming / user selection part.

Help / Guidance / code sample on how to create such a function will be appreciated.

Comment: _I did not find any reference on how to achieve this_ Really? There are [tons](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A3152130+chart+zoom) of it..

Comment: edited, please advise or refer to a reference

Comment: [Selecting](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A3152130+chart+select)

Comment: @TaW not sure if those events are what I need, they fire on user selection, where what I want is to narrow the X,Y range of the chart in advance. suggestion?

Comment: You can always do it in code as well by setting the [ScaleView](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datavisualization.charting.axis.scaleview?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Windows_Forms_DataVisualization_Charting_Axis_ScaleView) values: `...AxisX.ScaleView.Size = 3;  ...AxisX.ScaleView.Position = 3;`

Comment: "it simulates the behaviors of user selection" how exactly to you intend to simulate this? "zooms around a specific point range in the chart" is this for show purposes? spend a specific time at a certain range then move to another ?=!

Comment: MongZhu thanks, TaW last comment is exactly what I needed. @Taw if you can post it as an answer I will be able to credit it as the accepted solution. Thanks

Comment: Duplicate of [e.g. this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23542701/chart-compression/27077902#27077902)

Comment: mm.. did not think of using the search term "chart compression", got to know how to look ;), thanks.

Comment: You are right; 'compression' is not better-suited  than ''auto selection' to find it ;-)

Comment: ha ha, cheers and thanks,

Comment: Btw: To allow users to adapt the zoom range set `chartarea.CursorX.IsUserSelectionEnabled = true;`