# Removing Points From the Start of a Chart When Past a Certain Size in C#

Tags: c#, dynamic, charts, com, points

I am writing data to a chart from a COM port during run time. As such, the chart is dynamically updating but as it gets increasingly bigger, the scale changes making the line smaller and smaller. I wish to stop this by deleting points off the front of the chart after it's so big.

```
            if (chartMain.Series.Points.Count() >= 120)
            {
                chartMain.Series[0].Points.RemoveAt(0);
            }
```

I need something like this that deletes the first point after a certain size so the scale remains the same. However, it does not work in it's current form and I am unsure in how to approach the problem. Can anyone point me in the right direction? Thank you in advance.

Comment: a) there is no code showing how you add the data. - b) The condition is obviously the wrong way around. Change to `if (chartMain.Series[i].Points.Count <= 120) chartMain.Series[i].Points.RemoveAt(0);`  !! - c) if you have several series you add points to you will need to remove points from each as well..

Comment: Ah yes, I copied the wrong segment of code. Okay, I shall try that. Like I said, I didn't really know where to begin and a quick Google returned nothing on the matter. I shall take what you said into account. I shall also update the error in my question. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Your situation is very similar to this thread:

[Chart control X axis growing and growing and it looks like it not moving](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21894191/chart-control-x-axis-growing-and-growing-and-it-looks-like-it-not-moving)

Try this:

```
 if (chartMain.Series.Points.Count() >= 120)
 {
        chartMain.Series[0].Points.RemoveAt(0);
        chartMain.ResetAutoValues();
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
chartMain.ResetAutoValues();
```

instead of the above line, you can use the

```
// Adjust the X-axis range or scrolling to keep the chart within the field of view
            chartMain.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].AxisX.Minimum = chartMain.Series.Points.Count()-120;
            chartMain.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].AxisX.Maximum = 120;
```

this code will set the minimum to 120 less than your series points count. For example, when your series has 140 points, the chart will begin at point 20. If you series has 230 points, the chart will begin at 110th point. Which means, your chart will always display the latest 120 points.